# Use only left alt as modifier in i3wm?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, i3

Is it possible to **set modifier only to left alt**?

I need to write **special characters using right alt** (or **alt gr**), therefore I would like not to have right alt bound to i3wm shortcuts.

I've set mod using:

```
set $mod Mod1
```

Currently, both(left and right) alt keys are used as modifier by i3wm.

Output of `xmodmap -pm`:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: Sounds like you probably want to use `xmodmap`.

Comment: How did you configure your keyboard layout? What's the output of `xmodmap -pm`?

Comment: @Gilles I've added output of `xmodmap -pm`. It looks like mod1 is configured for both alt keys. Unfortunately, I've got no experience with xmodmap, yet.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (keycode 0x6c) configured so send the `mod1` modifier, same as the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. The right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key sends the `Alt_R` keysym. That means your right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is an Alt key, not an AltGr key. In order to make the key an AltGr key, you need to both make it send the `Mode_switch` keysym and a separate modifier. (If the keysym assignments and the modifier assignment are inconsistent, some applications will use one setting, some will use the other, and some will just behave strangely.)

Put these lines in `~/.Xmodmap` and arrange to run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` when you log in. I'm not sure about the effect of `ISO_Level3_Shift` (used for switching between layouts) being assigned to the same modifier; if that turns out to be a problem, put that and `Mod_switch` on different modifiers.

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch
add Mod5 = Mode_switch
```

If you change modifier assignments during a session, a few applications need to be restarted; I don't know if that's the case for i3wm.

Comment: Well, you've pointed me to right direction, but this configuration worked for me: `clear mod1 \n
keycode 0x6c = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift  NoSymbol \n 
add Mod1 = Alt_L \n 
add Mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift`

Comment: Actually effect of `ISO_Level3_Shift` is what `AltGr` should do, not the `Mode_switch`. Please correct the answer, and I'll accept it ;-)

Comment: @Miro `Mode_switch` is what AltGr sends when you configure the keyboard with xmodmap. If `ISO_Level3_Shift` works for you, you must be using XKB to set the layout, and in that case you should use the appropriate XKB option to make Alt_R be AltGr. I think you need to add `level3(ralt_switch)` to your symbols, e.g. `xsetxkbmap 'pc+inet(evdev)+fr+level3(ralt_switch)'` (replace `fr` by the code for your language's layout).